# Sort Date or String type in one c# method

Tags: c#

Environment: Visual Studio 2008 SP1, FX3.5 
The method below shows how I can sort a list by date. Is there a way to make that more generic? For example, can I make it accept a string list or a date list and then sort. I was thinking maybe use DateTime.TryParse and if it's a date then list is a date then sort by DateTime, otherwise it's a list of string and sort by that instead.

```
public class Helpers
{
    public static List<DateTime> SortAscending(List<DateTime> list)
    {
    list.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
    return list;
    }

    public static List<DateTime> SortDescending(List<DateTime> list)
    {
    list.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));
    return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use list.OrderBy()?

Comment: Have a look at [Enumerable.OrderBy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) and [Enumerable.OrderByDescending Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method could easily be changed to:

```
public static List<T> SortAscending(List<T> list) where T : IComparable
{
    list.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
    return list;
}

public static List<T> SortDescending(List<T> list) where T : IComparable
{
    list.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));
    return list;
}
```

Which will allow you to sort a List of any type that implements `IComparable`.